# Not able to assign right axis to a determined series in a Google Sheets Chart via App Script

Tags: google-sheets, charts, google-visualization

I´ve been trying to use google appscript to assign the right axis to a series called "Peso Corporal (Kg)" in a chart to which you can add/delete new series using checkboxes (hence the importance of the name).

This is what I've tried but it has no effect in my chart.

```
function assignRightAxis() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("DASHBOARD");
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
  chart = chart.modify()
    .setOption("series", {
      "Peso Corporal (Kg)": {targetAxisIndex: 1}
    })
    .build();
  sheet.updateChart(chart);
}
```

I'm new to App Script so mistakes may be present.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `assign the right axis to a series called "Peso Corporal (Kg)" in a chart to which you can add/delete new series using checkboxes (hence the importance of the name).`. Can I ask you the detail of your question?

Comment: pretty sure you need to use the series index vs. name